# Save filtered data from filter pipe Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, datatable, pipe

My pipe is :

```
@Pipe({
    name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
        if (query) {
            return _.filter(array, row=>row.name.indexOf(query) > -1);
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

My html file:

```
  <table class="table table-striped"  [mfData]="listdata | dataFilter : filterQuery " #mf="mfDataTable"
                   [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
```

I am using angular2-datatable.

I am filtering data using this pipe and displaying it in a datatable.
I want to save the filtered data in a variable so I can use it elsewhere in my application.

Comment: **Pipes transform displayed values within a template.** - is the definition of pipe in angular. Why do you want to save it?

Comment: @Aravind I have a list of locations in a data table. If the user filters the list ,I want to only view those filtered locations using markers on a google map.

Comment: you should allow the user to `select from the list` which is what you should be saving in DB

Answer (score 1):

Provide the Pipe in your module:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [DataFilterPipe]
})
export class MyModule {
    ...
}
```

Then inject and use it in your component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public filtered;

    constructor(private dataFilterPipe: DataFilterPipe) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const unfiltered = ...;
        const filterQuery = ...;
        this.filtered = this.dataFilterPipe.transform(unfiltered, filterQuery);
    }
}
```

You could now bind your datatable directly to the `filtered` property to avoid filtering twice:

```
<table [mfData]="filtered" ...>
```

Though now I would wonder if you need to declare a pipe at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I want to know why do I have to use this inside the constructor?

Comment: You don't have to use it inside the constructor. See my edit.